# How to locate the upper child element using xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

```
<div> 
  <input>
   <label id="Star">
    <input>
    <label id="Moon">
    <input>
    <label id="Sun">
</div>
```

Query:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label(@id='star')/parent::div/input`).
```

I am getting the 3 matching nodes but I need to find the `<label id="Star">` of `<input>.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply wrap using xpath indexing :

```
(//label(@id='star')/parent::div/input)[1]
```

should point to first input, for second change that to [2] and so on..

**Update 1 :**

if input is parent then this :

```
//label[@id='Star']/..
```

if input is preceding-sibling then this :

```
//label[@id='Star']/preceding-sibling::input
```

I believe you are looking for  **preceding-sibling**

Comment: yes, but if i don't want to used indexing then what will be the solution.?

Comment: If I want the <label id="Sun"> of <input> of xpath then again I'm getting the 3 matching nodes using preceding-sibling. so how to get the each <label> of uppar node i.e. <input> using it's id.

Comment: it depends on other HTML nodes you see in HTML DOM, indexing is last resort, you may need to consider that as well. there's no harm in indexing

Comment: `//label[@id='Sun']/preceding-sibling::input[last()]` - try this as well.